# Datadog agent scrub password from an url

Tags: datadog

I am following the documentation to [scrub sensitive data from your logs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=docker#scrub-sensitive-data-from-your-logs) in a docker environment.

I am looking for the correct label to use to scrub password from this log

```
XXX url=https://username:password@host:port/path response_code=200 return_code=ok
```

I want this result for my log

```
XXX url=https://username:****@host:port/path response_code=200 return_code=ok
```

So I guess I should do something like this...

```yaml
labels:
  com.datadoghq.ad.logs: >-
      [{
      "source": "app",
      "service": "api",
      "log_processing_rules": [{
          "type": "mask_sequences",
          "name": "mask_password",
          "replace_placeholder": "$1$2:****@$4",
          "pattern" : "(?<protocol>.+?\/\/)(?<username>.+?):(?<password>.+?)@(?<address>.+)"
        }]
      }]
```

What are the values I should use for `pattern` and `replace_placeholder` ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/7bVWAX/1): `https://(.*):(.*)@`

This will give you two captures, so username will be in `$1` and password in `$2`. So for your placeholder, try `https://{$1}:xxxx@`